# How do I write a web part that pops up "Hello world" using jQuery?

Tags: web-part, jquery

I want to use jQuery in my SP2010 hello world web part which pops up "Hello world" using jQuery. What do I have to do?  I know I can do this with JavaScript, but I want to learn about jQuery in web part development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Site doesn't support JQuery from scratch. You have to add it manually. It can be done in several ways:

**Step 1.** Adding JQuery :

1) Deploy JQuery as a custom feature.

*Or*

2) Upload JQuery as a simple file to the document library.

**Step 2.** Adding reference to the JQuery :

1.1) Create custom master page with reference to the JQuery.

1.2) Create web site based on the custom master page.

*Or*

2) Add Content Editor web part to the page. In the web part's properties specify the link to the file.

However to show Dialogue in SP 2010 you should use [SP.js](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee552096.aspx). Just add the reference to SP.js in the page and call `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()` function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you're going to learn by doing this over and above just using jQuery on a non-SharePoint html page but...

- Go to a web part page or wiki page
  you've setup.
- Select Site Actions > Edit Page Click "Add a web part"
- Select Media and Content > Content Editor
- Select “Click here to add new
  content” On the ribbon select Html >
  Edit HTML Source

[image: Sp2010 Foundation CEWP Edit HTML Source]

Then paste the javascript/jquery you want to put on the page.

To get inspiration on what you can do with javascipt and SharePoint start with [Christophe's blog](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/) + see also [JQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) site

Comment: JUST an FYI...New Content Editor WebPart (2010) strips out all the script added to the HTML source. Only Option left is to create a htm or txt file in any doc lib and link the Content Editor WebPart to it.

Comment: No it doesn't. If you try and put script directly into a wiki page (even when using source) then yes it will - but if you put it into a CEWP it does't. Don't take my word for it - http://sympmarc.com/2011/03/29/adding-script-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp-in-sharepoint-2010/